# How to check that lines in a file are alphabetically sorted

Tags: files, sort

As a sanity check, I'd like to verify that the lines in a file are sorted alphabetically. I do not wish to *sort* the file alphabetically (the file is expected to be sorted already). I wish only to verify that it is indeed sorted.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119733/discussion-on-question-by-pseudosudo-how-to-check-that-lines-in-a-file-is-alphab).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sort -c` will do what you want. As the GNU man page makes clear, this does not attempt to sort the input, it only checks if it's sorted. It is actually not the case that the only way to check if a file is sorted is to sort it again and see if it's different - you only need to read the file and make sure that each record sorts higher (or lower, as appropriate) than the one before it. However, there is no way to avoid at least reading the entire file (unless you find a record out of order, in which case you can just stop right at that point).